# How to start activity as paused or so on

Tags: android

I have Tabview and I want do send data from one to another. Eatch is represent by it´s own activity. I use this to send String[] array to another activity, but i want to stay in first activity. How to?

```
Bundle b=new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("key", arr);
        Intent intent=new Intent(this, ActivityTo.class);
        intent.putExtras(b);
```

This:

```
    intent.putExtras(b);
```

Starts new activity. Is posibble to start activity on backround or someting like that so I can stay in my first activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the methods described in the [Android Application FAQ](http://developer.android.com/resources/faq/framework.html#3). But I think that there's something not right with your design because generally one activity shouldn't depend directly on the instance of another activity.